# Replacing a certain number of characters after a match using sed with {,/ and "

Tags: shell, sed

I need to replace whatever is there after `\"db_password\":\"` up to 16 characters (passwords) with `<sensitive>`:

```
data_json: "{\"db_password\":\"qwHLI?mkSrQ=GHU_\"}" => "{\"db_password\":\"BoBBsR9PA]wZ_3AC\"}"
```

should be

```
data_json: "{\"db_password\":\"sensitive\"}" => "{\"db_password\":\"sensitive\"}"
```

I have tried following but not sure how to escape `{`, `\` and `"`.

```
sed -E 's/("{\"db_password\":\").{16}/\<sensitive>/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat jsonfile
#=> data_json: "{\"db_password\":\"qwHLI?mkSrQ=GHU_\"}" => "{\"db_password\":\"BoBBsR9PA]wZ_3AC\"}"

sed -E 's/("\{\\"db_password\\":\\").{16}/\1sensitive/g' jsonfile
#=> data_json: "{\"db_password\":\"sensitive\"}" => "{\"db_password\":\"sensitive\"}"
```

You need escape `\` too. Also `\1` to reference the first pair `()` matched content.
`<>` is unnessary here.

**Update**: without the 16 chars password limitation:

```
sed -E 's/("\{\\"db_password\\":\\")[^"\]+/\1sensitive/g' jsonfile
#=> data_json: "{\"db_password\":\"sensitive\"}" => "{\"db_password\":\"sensitive\"}"
```

This will replace password of any passwords. (Well, can't have `\` in passwords.)

Comment: It works if and only if the length of password is exactly 16 chars, although I'm not sure whether it *is* what the OP want to do.

Comment: @tshiono  OP's code showed that he wants it this way. Anyway, I'll update it later today.

Comment: I don't want you to be offended. I've been often pointed out the incompleteness of my answer by fuddy-duddies even if I've traced the OP's code fragment which is not essential to the question. It is a dilemma to find a balance between the faultless code and paying regard to the OP's code.

Comment: Well OP is generating 16 characters, so it should be ok.

Comment: @tshiono Non taken. I'll take them as opportunities to improve myself, either technically or mentally. Thanks for reminding me :)